# Group multiple documents of facet

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to group my documents by _id, I made a query that is true when a match is valid to categorize my results, however each match generates a document, I would like to group all the documents of equal _id in one. Was there any other way to do that? When finding a specific condition of a match he will return me which condition he found

I already tried using `$group:{_id:{"$_id"} }`

```
db.collection('data').aggregate( [
    {
        $facet: {
            "teste1": [
                { $match: { "estabelecimento": {$regex: palavra, $options:'i'} } },
                { $addFields: { "teste1": true } }
            ],
            "teste2": [
                { $match: { "nome": {$regex: palavra, $options:'i'} } },
                { $addFields: { "teste2": true } }
            ],
            "teste3": [
                { $match: { "tags": {$regex: palavra, $options:'i'} } },
                { $addFields: { "teste3": true } }
            ]
        }
    }, {
        $project: { 
            "allDocuments" : { $setUnion: [ "$teste1", "$teste2", "$teste3" ] } 
        }
    }, {
        $unwind: "$allDocuments" 
    }, {
        $replaceRoot: { 
            newRoot: "$allDocuments"
        }
    }, {
        $project: { 
            "nome": 1,
            "seller_id":1,
            "descricao":1,
            "tags":1,
            "estabelecimento":1,
            "teste1": 1,
            "teste2":1,
            "teste3":1
        }
    }
])
```

My current result:

```
  {
    _id: 5d29e0f9942fdb56a515ffd4,
    seller_id: 10,
    nome: 'nescau',
    descricao: 'nescau eh muito gostoso',
    estabelecimento: 'Nescaleiro',
    tags: 'chocolate,nescaus,achocolatado',
    teste1: true
  },
  {
    _id: 5d29e0f9942fdb56a515ffd4,
    seller_id: 10,
    nome: 'nescau',
    descricao: 'nescau eh muito gostoso',
    estabelecimento: 'Nescaleiro',
    tags: 'chocolate,nescaus,achocolatado',
    teste2: true
  },
  {
    _id: 5d29e0f9942fdb56a515ffd4,
    seller_id: 10,
    nome: 'nescau',
    descricao: 'nescau eh muito gostoso',
    estabelecimento: 'Nescaleiro',
    tags: 'chocolate,nescaus,achocolatado',
    teste3: true
  }
```

I would like to receive:

```
  {
    _id: 5d29e0f9942fdb56a515ffd4,
    seller_id: 10,
    nome: 'nescau',
    descricao: 'nescau eh muito gostoso',
    estabelecimento: 'Nescaleiro',
    tags: 'chocolate,nescaus,achocolatado',
    teste1: true,
    teste2: true,
    teste3: true
  }
```

Comment: Don't do facets, $or and $addFields is enough.

Comment: I need use multiples $or? @AlexBlex

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. You match documents where at least 1 of 3 fields match the regex, yes? So it is an [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or)

Comment: I've changed all the facets for items in $or, and the result is null

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. It's x-y problem. You don't need facets, setUnion, unwind, grouping etc. The approach based on facets is wrong. You can get your documents  with a much simpler pipeline with only $match and $addFields stages.

Answer (score 0):

Speculating without examples of the documents, the pipeline could be something like this:

```
db.collection('data').aggregate( [
    {
        $match: { $or: [ 
            { "estabelecimento": {$regex: palavra, $options:'i'} }, 
            { "nome": {$regex: palavra, $options:'i'} },
            { "tags": {$regex: palavra, $options:'i'} }
        ] }
    }, {
        $addFields: { 
            teste1: { $regexMatch: { input: "$estabelecimento", regex: /palavra/i } },
            teste2: { $regexMatch: { input: "$nome", regex: /palavra/i } },
            teste3: { $regexMatch: { input: "$tags", regex: /palavra/i } }
        }
    }
])
```